# What does fractional value represent for distance correlation?

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation, distance-covariance

I understand that if distance correlation is 1, then it's statistically dependent but independent if 0.

But if distance correlation turns out to be about, say, 0.65 or 0.5

what does that mean in general?

Comment: The figure displayed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) provides one of the best possible answers to this question: it shows a range of bivariate behaviors and their associated distance correlation values.